# API returning Name Value Pairs Deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deserialization

We're accessing an api using ASP.NET MVC 5 (C#) that is returning semi-colon delimited Name-Value Pairs:

```
Field1=Value1;Field2=Value2;Field3=Value3;...;FieldN=ValueN
```

currently we're manually using the split function and matching fields to rows of the array generated by the split function. I was wondering is there a better way of doing this. Is there a built in Deserialization method that will handle this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to respect any standard data format and I don't think that there's a built-in class to handle this custom format. There are built-in deserializers for standard data formats such as `application/json`, `application/xml`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. What you have shown looks close to CSV, so you might consider using a CSV parser such as [`CsvHelper`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to extract the necessary information. But since you have `key=value` pairs, you will still need to parse them manually.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I really don't know why the owners of the api decided to do it this way but we have to use them and I guess I have to do it manually.